# How to create oauth2 token request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, axios

I'm making several attempts to generate an oauth2 token using axes in NodeJS with all these fields that are mandatory to generate.
I am successfully managing to generate in Postman, but without success in my project. How could I generate?

with the code below you only receive: {"error": "invalid_client"}

[Postman fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjVgD.png)

[Code to get token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2XE2.png)

Comment: you should share your project settings, what you have tried so far, on which points you struggled etc.

Comment: const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xx.com.br/api/v1/oauth/auth/token',
  headers:
  {
   'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  form:
  {
   client_id: 'xx',
   client_secret: 'xx',
   username: 'xx@gmail.com',
   password: 'xx',
   scope: 'xx',
   grant_type: 'xx'
  }
 };

 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
 });